# What kind of pick does it take to mine Emeralds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just found my first emeralds, and I'm scared to mine it lest I mine it with the wrong pick and thus lose it.  I'm very early in my game, so I don't have an iron pick yet, but don't want to forget where the emerald is.

I thought [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Emerald) would have this information, but it doesn't appear to.

What kind of pick does it take to mine Emeralds?

Comment: Saw this got bumped and felt like it's worth noting that it's typically very obvious if you're using the wrong pick - it takes FOREVER to mine something incorrectly.  Obsidian is the only thing that's normally that slow.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Emeralds can only be mined from the ore with an **Iron, Diamond, or Netherite pickaxe**.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Emerald_Ore)

Comment: Don't forget that like mining diamonds you should also use a pick enchanted with Fortune to maximise loot drop. That way you can get more than one drop per block mined.

Answer (score 2):

You must use an Iron Pick or better to mine emeralds

Answer (score -2):

You can use iron or diamond, it doesn't make a difference.